# How to check if List < int[ ] > contains an int[] element that store the same values as another int[ ]?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say, that I have a list of integer arrays and an integer array:

```
List<int[]> MyListOfIntArrays = new List<int[]>
                                 {
                                      new int[1] {0},
                                      new int[2] {0,1},
                                      new int[2] {1,0}
                                 };
int[] MyArray = new int[]{1, 0};
```

I want to find out how can I check if in MyListOfIntArrays is an element that stores the same values as MyArray. 
In this case the answer should be: "Yes" (third element of MyListOfIntArrays stores the same values as MyArray).

My attempt:

```
if (MyListOfIntArrays.Contains(MyArray) == true)
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
if (MyListOfIntArrays.Contains(MyArray) == false)
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

always returns no. 
I'm new to C# and my guess is that the method "Contains" checks references here, not values. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindIndex` and `SequenceEqual`.

`FindIndex` will return the index of given array(`MyListOfIntArrays`) when ever predicate returns true. it will return -1 if it wasnt able to find anything.

`SequenceEqual` will check the equality of arrays element by element instead of checking references which `Contains` normally do (because it uses default comparer and arrays are checked by ref. another way is to use custom comparer showed by Servy).

```
if (MyListOfIntArrays.FindIndex(x => x.SequenceEqual(MyArray)) != -1) // if != -1 means we found array!
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

You may want to make it simple if you dont need index. `Any` will Just give a Boolean And as commented by Asad Saeeduddin:

```
if(MyListOfIntArrays.Any(MyArray.SequenceEqual))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you also just use `Any` here instead of doing `FindIndex` and `!= -1`? I haven't tested, but I think you could just simplify this to `if(MyListOfIntArrays.Any(MyArray.SequenceEqual))`

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
var contains = MyListOfIntArrays.Any(arr => arr.GetType() == MyArray.GetType() && arr.SequenceEqual(MyArray));
```

Edit:

As both comments suggested, it can be shortened to

```
var contains = MyListOfIntArrays.Any(arr => arr.SequenceEqual(MyArray));
```

Comment: what is `arr.GetType() == MyArray.GetType()` for?

Comment: `SequenceEqual` works on `IEnumerable`s, so it would return true if you compared for example an array and a List<int>, which shouldn't return true

Comment: @w.b You can't put a `List<int>` into a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: good note. but i dont think there is need to do extra things. op didnt say he would pass list.

Answer (score 0):

The equality that arrays have defined for themselves only checks if the arrays reference the same object; it doesn't check if the contents of the arrays are the same.  If you want to compare them based on their values, you'll need to create a comparer that can compare the values of the arrays:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
                hash = hash * 79 + comparer.GetHashCode(item);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you write:

```
if (MyListOfIntArrays.Contains(MyArray, new SequenceComparer<int>()))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

Answer (score -1):

`.Contains` will not work, since arrays are reference types, and you will only get true if you've added the array that `MyArray` points to specifically to the list, instead of an identical array.

While you can solve your problem using elementwise comparison against all arrays, I feel a better solution to the problem would be to use sets instead of arrays. If you had an `ISet<ISet<int>>` instead of a `List<int[]>`, you could very easily and efficiently check if a given `ISet<int>` was a member.

Comment: You *can* use `Contains` by providing a custom comparer.  `Contains` doesn't compare the references because arrays are reference types, it does so because *that's what the array type defined equality as for itself*.  If it had overridden its own equality members to check the values, then that's what it would do.  Of course, it didn't, but it has nothing to do with it being a reference type, but rather a design decision of its creators. If the outer collection is a set you can check to see if a given inner collection exists quicker, yes, but there's no need for the inner collection to be a set.

Comment: @Servy The default equality comparison for reference types is reference equality, so I'm not sure what your point here is. I haven't checked the reference source, but I'm fairly certain arrays didn't have to override the equality operator to implement what they get by default by virtue of being reference types.

Comment: The fact that that's the default implementation is *irrelevant*.  Arrays don't use references for equality because they're reference types, they do so because the designer of the type choose that functionality.  If they wanted to compare the values of the arrays, they could have, and other reference types do exactly that.  So arrays are compared based on their reference because *that's how the designers choose to compare them* and not because they were forced to as a result of the fact that it's a reference type.  That the result is that they don't have to implement anything doesn't matter.

Comment: @Servy The designers made no conscious decision to compare arrays in any particular way. Comparison logic for arrays is the default for reference types; i.e. if they're the same reference, they're equal. Of course you *can* override the equality operator, but no one did, so I don't understand what you're trying to convey here.

Comment: What's your basis for asserting that nobody ever considered how arrays should define equality, and that nobody ever even considered implementing any other behavior?  The fact that the implementation happens to be the default in no way means that it wasn't an intentional decision.  Again, you didn't say that arrays happen to compare themselves based on their reference, you said that they do so *specifically because they're reference types*.  That's not true.  That's how they compare themselves because that's what the designers choose.  They could easily have chosen something else.

Comment: It isn't my job to prove a negative; the onus is on you to back up your claim that the reference type equality that every reference type gets out of the box was somehow a very deeply considered and pondered issue for this one specific type.

Comment: @Servy Regarding, "you didn't say that arrays happen to compare themselves based on their reference, you said that they do so specifically because they're reference types"; that's quite a stretch. I said in my answer that `Contains` will not work because arrays are reference types, which is true; if the elements were structs, the default equality comparison would have been bitwise equality, which would have worked as the OP expected. Regardless, it's been fun engaging in yet another session of useless pedantry with you.

Comment: Your assertions are only true if you take as an assumption that the equality for the type will always and forever be the default behavior.  That's a false assumption, and so the logical statement doesn't hold.  Simply considering any reference type that *doesn't* rely on the default behavior (say `string`) trivially demonstrates this.